# Issue in converting object to yaml using Jackson YAMLFactory

Tags: java, json, jackson, yaml, objectmapper

I have multiple objects that needs to be converted to a single YAML file using Jackson YAMLFactory ObjectMapper.

Below is my root object:

```
    public class RootClass {
    
        @JsonProperty("load_from")
        List<Class A> loadFrom();

         //getters and setters here
    }
```

Class A:

```
public Class A {

    @JsonProperty("python_file")
    Set<Class B> pythonFiles();
//getter setters below

}
```

Class B:

```
public class B {

    @JsonProperty("relative_path")
    public String relativePath();

    @JsonProperty("location_name")
    public String locationName();

  //getter setters below

}
```

this is how I construct my ObjectMapper object below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER,false)
                .configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.INDENT_ARRAYS_WITH_INDICATOR, true)
        );
        mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
        mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
```

With the above code when I try to write YAML file from my root object (assuming all values are set properly), I get below YAML file generated:

```
load_from:
  - python_file:
      - relative_path: "testRelativepath"
        location_name: "TestLocation"
```

However, in this YAML file, there is only 1 issue which I am trying to figure out how to fix.
There **should not be a hyphen** appended to **relative_path** .

The expected YAML output should be as below:

```
load_from:
  - python_file:
       relative_path: "testRelativepath"
       location_name: "TestLocation"
```

I also tried adding this to my objectmapper configuration

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED);
```

But then when there is only single element in `Set<Class B>` then the YAML is generated as below without any array type:

```
load_from:
   python_file:
       relative_path: "testRelativepath"
       location_name: "TestLocation"
```

Also, I figured out that this happens only when I have a single object in the `Set<Class B>`, if there are multiple elements in the `Set<Class B>`, the code works fine as expected.

Can anyone please help in this?